# Criar uma box de tamanho único com barra de rolagem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero criar um box que tenha um tamanho único, mas que tenha barra de rolagem nele para visualizar o conteúdo completo.

Quero usar isso para detalhar algo.

Comment: Pode ser com CSS?

Answer (score 1):

No CSS adicione

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Answer (score 1):

Na classe do elemento adicione:

```
overflow-x : scroll;
```